# Get Unlink to Work

Tags: php

Trying to delete a file, but it refuses to be deleted.  I've tried the following which has if statement that check the file already exists & other .db file is blank.  Path is correct, setting it to 666 so can delete, then unlink, then writing the file back with the word "open" in it.

```
if(file_exists("results_files/linktracker/linktrackerlock.txt") && file_get_contents("results_files/linktracker/linktracker.db") == "") {  // check for reset condition, ie. db file wiped
    chmod("results_files/linktracker/linktrackerlock.txt", 0666);
    unlink("results_files/linktracker/linktrackerlock.txt");
    file_put_contents("results_files/linktracker/linktrackerlock.txt", "open");
}
```

Comment: And what error message do you receive?

Comment: Did you mean `chmod` instead of `chown` and `0666` instead of `666`?

Comment: Definitely be careful with the octal and decimal - `0666` is not the same as `666`.  I really can't believe that PHP does not include usable constants from `<sys/stat.h>` anywhere other than `dio`...

Comment: @D.Shawley  Thanks, see updates above.   No error messages.  Still showing the old file contents, instead of "open".  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @parti. Turn on error reporting (`error_reporting(E_ALL)`) and check the return value of `unlink`.  Unlink doesn't really delete the file, it simply dereferences the directory entry.

Comment: @D.Shawley  Ok, I placed error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1'); after the opening php call. I don't see any errors on the page - but still showing old file contents. New to this - so help is appreciated.

Comment: I got it working - it was the if's 2nd condition that was the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`chown` will change the ownership of the file passed as first argument, you are probably better off using `chmod` (which is used to change permissions).

Comment: OK updated to chmod w/ the 0666, but it's still showing the old file conntents, instead of "open" ?